# Why do we have a version tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a [version](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version) tag. Is this is a useful tag?

Comment: I think it adds little to no value and would agree to getting rid of it.

Comment: It has a use, but not enough of one to keep it.

Comment: Not that many [tag:version] questions remain, appropriately re-tagging them will take care of the tag naturally /cc: @Dynamic

Comment: @YannisRizos Done :)

Answer (score 5):

Looking through the questions, it appears this tag is used to indicate choosing/using/managing particular versions of software libraries or tools, version control practices, or configuration/release management practices. There's really nothing that I would synonymize version with outright and I'm not sure I'd black list it, but for the questions with that tag right now, it seems like the tag either adds no value or doesn't adequately describe the subject matter of the question.

Comment: At first I thought we could merge with [tag:versioning], but looking at the questions it wouldn't really make sense for most questions. Retagged about half of them, and deleted a couple closed ones, the tag will naturally go away when it has no questions left.

Comment: If there are any left at lunch, I might do a few then unless there are already some old ones bumped up still. A manual process isn't that bad here.